# LINQ to SQL Select Distinct by Multiple Columns and return entire entity

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

I am working with a third party database and need to select a distinct set of data for the specific market that I am looking into. The data is the same for each market, so it is redundant to pull it all in, and I don't want to hardcode any logic around it as we are working with the vendor to fix the issue, but we need a fix that will work with the vendors fix as well as the way the database is currently as it could be some time before thier fix goes live.

I do not want to group by anything as I want to get the data at the lowest level, but I don't want any redundant data. My current query looks similar to this...

```
determinantData = (from x in dbContext.Datas
                   where x.Bar.Name.Equals(barName) &&
                         x.Something.Name.Equals(someName) &&
                         FooIds.Contains(x.Foo.Id) &&
                         x.Date >= startDate && 
                         x.Date <= endDate
                   select x).Distinct();
```

This does not do what I expect. I would like to select the distinct records by three properties, say `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Something` but return the entire object. How can I do this using LINQ?

Comment: This "I do not want to group by anything as I want to get the data at the lowest level, but I don't want any redundant data" does not make sense.  Selecting distinct and grouping by do the same thing, but if you group you can also have aggregate functions in the select list.

Comment: I realize this, I just didn't know how to ask it in a better way.. basically I don't want to aggregate the other data that is not part of the distinction but I still want to select that data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could use `group by` with the properties that you want to be distinct, then select the first item of each group:

```
determinantData = (from x in dbContext.Datas
                   where x.Bar.Name.Equals(barName) &&
                         x.Something.Name.Equals(someName) &&
                         FooIds.Contains(x.Foo.Id) &&
                         x.Date >= startDate && 
                         x.Date <= endDate
                   group x by new { x.Foo, x.Bar, x.Something } into market 
                   select market).Select( g=> g.First());
```

Comment: While this works, it is drastically affecting performance of the report generation. The report usually generates in under ten seconds and is now taking over a minute. +1 for the solution, but any way to fix the performance hit?

Comment: actually, after running a few more tests, it is closer to 3 minutes to generate the report.

Comment: @shuniar: an alternative is to use `AsEnumerable()` to do the grouping in memory on the datas that matched. Then you can also use `DistinctBy` from the MoreLinq project: http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs

Comment: I ended up using the DistinctBy method from MoreLinq and it sped up my query. I had to `ToList()` my data before the call though because I was running into the "another data reader is already associated..." exception. But still, much faster than initially. Marked as answer, thanks!