# use safe cast (as) with mongoDb C# driver and linq

Tags: linq, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm attempting to use Odata and web-api with mongoDb. The web-api library applies linq queries across an IQueryable in order to query it. One of the queries I'm required to support involves a cast. web-api returns an IQueryable with the expression

```
value.where(it => ((it.property as Child).Value == "example"));
```

This results in

```
Unable to determine the serialization information for the expression:
<TypeAs>it.Property.Value
```

is there a way to modify the expression once I get the IQueryable so that it performs an
**is** check and then a cast, as this is supported by the C# driver. Alternatively is there a library which provides this support already?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11362594/selecting-a-new-type-from-linq-query

Comment: thanks for the idea, however I need to handle large amounts of data so that fix wont work for me.